Dual boot does not work after moving my hard drive to a new laptop
I have an old Lenovo laptop that died, so I bought the exact same one on Ebay for 80 bucks. I moved my current hard drive to the new laptop and it now boots straight to Windows.
Normally I get the Grub menu and can choose between EOS and Windows. How do I get back to that?

Probably, the issue is in the boot order in the BIOS
Here some tips to resolve this issue:

Go to the BIOS To do that, by default you should hit the F2 key while turning on the laptop. If it not works, specify the exact laptop model for me or try to do your own research.

Navigate to the Boot or Startup section Use the arrow keys.

Probably you will have something like this in the Boot order:

Windows Boot Manager
ubuntu (i have ubuntu label for grub, but  i dont know about you)


Using the F6/F5 keys move ubuntu (or whatever) up and Windows Boot Manager down


If this doesn't work for you, please share some more details, as exact laptop model, BIOS photo and the Boot or Startup page.
